# Tinymce html clean up

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

Is there a way where i can stop tinymce from change my html code. 
When i go to code view and back to the WSIWYG editor, i don't wont't it too change any thing even if it thinks it is wrong.

Atm me biggest problem is it remove a tag.

If you write

```
<a href="something"><div>link</div></a>
```

it will remove the a tag.

i have try:

entity_encoding: "raw"

cleanup_on_startup: false

trim_span_elements: false

verify_html: false

cleanup: false

valid_elements

extended_valid_elements

Comment: possible duplicate of [TinyMCE 4 disable cleanup html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364133/tinymce-4-disable-cleanup-html)